# Black space above bottom nav bar on xl screens only

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image: The blue is the bottom of the app]I have built my android app and all is working well except for xl screens such as a pixel 3 xl. On these larger screens the app doesn't fill the full length of the screen, so there is a black bar between the bottom of the app and the nav bar. Works perfectly on all smaller sizes.

Not sure what code to show so please just let me know what you need to see. Testing on Android 9.0 (same in emulator and physical devices).

Thanks!

Comment: Upload a screenshot

Comment: Add some code that you have tried!!

Comment: As I said, I don't know what file would manage this. It's a fully working app - What to you want to see? The manifest file? What should I be looking for?

Comment: I think you will get this fixed if you set the target SDK as 28.  Just a guess